# Scifi novel about galactic students fighting in gladiator-style games

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a science fiction novel I read in the early 1980s about a group of young adults on a sort of university or academy spaceship travelling the galaxy. On  one planet they stop at they are coerced into taking part in gladiatorial games with the dead losers being described as "perdido" (lost/forgotten) and never spoken of again. I seem to recall the gladiator planet was called "Hel" or "Hell" and the residents were called "Hellers".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[There is No Darkness](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?50929) by Joe and Jack Haldeman matches well.

Contains the elements of young adults on a galactic tour, gladatorial games, and the Hellers.  The ship was called *Starschool*.

The sections of the book are "Earth", "Hell", and "Construct".

> Curriculum Notes - Earth
>
> Most of what people think they know about Earth is wrong.

...................

> Curriculum Notes- Hell
>
> Hell is the fourth planet out from the star Delta Pavonis.

...................

Just flipping through it, it looks like the gladiatorial games actually took place on Earth.  I need to re-read this.

Comment: The summary on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/995860.There_Is_No_Darkness) matches pretty well.

Comment: Huh.  Nobody's ever asked about this before.  At one time I kept losing my copy, and wanting to re-read it, so I ended up with 3 copies of it.

Comment: @DavidW same thing happened to me with "Thrice Upon A Time".

Comment: Yes! This is it, thank you. Main character's name was Carl Bok and once I looked up the cover it all clicked. Great and fast help, going to buy another copy today.